# Which vehicle is more appropriate for the mountain stage of Hill Climb Racing?

Tags: android, hill-climb-racing

Which vehicle is more appropriate for the "Mountain" stage of [Hill Climb Racing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fingersoft.hillclimb)?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although **tank** doesn't look like the best vehicle, I found it very good to use in mountain level when all attributes are maxed.

Answer (score 6):

By my experience, the best vehicle is the super diesel 4x4. It allows you to go upwards easily and is difficult to turn down. Also, you will have enough fuel to think about the difficult jumps (or try again some of them) due to its long duration fuel.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have every vehicle unlocked, but I got pretty far with monster truck and super diesel 4x4. I don't think there is one vehicle that is the best, but a vehicle type.

Mountain is very, well, mounatainy. So you want a vehicle with good climbing ability, but not too much power that you just flip over when trying to climb. I would guess that the dune buggy and hovercraft would work very well here as their descriptions say that they are the best climbers (but again, I don't have them unlocked)

Answer (score 3):

I unlocked all the vehicles and stages.
According to me, the super diesel 4×4 and the race car are the best, as you need speed to cross this stage. You can also try the race car or dragster.

Answer (score 3):

My current best is 1850m with the Hovercraft (stability 18/20), so you could probably do more.

I pretty much touch only with the back of the car, the advantage is that you can go vertically upwards, as long as something is touching the ground. Plus you can't get stuck in a small dip in the terrain.

Answer (score 2):

The Mountain stage works best with vehicles that are good at making short, steep climbs, and are resilient to flipping. Generally, that means the Tank, and in my experience this stage is no exception. My best run has by far been with the Tank, at 2114 meters. Next up is Monster Truck at only 1363 meters. The treads on the tank also handle the large number of sharp points very well, when other vehicles get stuck with a tire on either side of the point.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be dune buggy or snow mobile because of their good traction and great speeds needed to climb tall and steep hills. Also the dune buggy has a good suspension for the bumps but it is easily flipped over